# How to keep a rand var the same after the first time

Tags: python-3.x

So I have:

```
Num = random.randint(1,100)
Print(Num)
Num - 20
Print(Num)
```

And I want it to print the original rand number - 20, how wold I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> @MrGeek is right. @ScottPickslay, just saying **Num - 20** will calculate the answer you're looking for but you are not using that answer. By saying **Num = num - 20**, you are storing the answer of **Num -20** back into Num.

```
Num = random.randint(1,100)
Print(Num) # Lets say this outputs the number 57
Num = Num - 20
Print(Num) # Then this will now be 37
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the result of subtraction back to `Num`, don't just calculate it:

```
Num = Num - 20
```

Or:

```
Num -= 20
```